# Let $f\geq0$ and that $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt<e^x$ for all $0\leq x$, show $f(t)e^{-at}\in L^1[0,\infty)$, $a>1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\geq0$ and that $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt<e^x$ for all $0\leq x$, show $f(t)e^{-at}\in L^1[0,\infty)$, $a>1$

I have a proof by i am not  sure if what I do is actually allowed. Define $h(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)$, then we know that $h'=f$ a.e and so $$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-at}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty} h'(t)e^{-at}dt=[h(t)e^{-at}]_0^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty} h(t)e^{-at}dt=-\int_{0}^{\infty} h(t)e^{-at}dt<-\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{1-at}<\infty$$

I used integration by parts but I am not sure I can do that. What are the conditions for Lebesgue integration to use integration by parts? Differentiable a.e is sufficient? And what is the actual solution here? We actually know $h$ is AC so perhaps this proof is fine after all.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $f$?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud f is a positive measurable function.

Comment: Absolute value of the last integral is less $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(a-1)t}\,dt = \frac{1}{a-1}$ and hence finite. Otherwise the proof looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without IBP and any regularity assumption: you have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{+ \infty} f(t) e^{-at} \: \mathrm{d} t & = \sum_{n \geq 0} \int_n^{n+1} f(t) e^{-at} \: \mathrm{d} t \\
& \leq \sum_{n \geq 0} e^{-an} \int_n^{n+1} f(t) \: \mathrm{d} t \\
& \leq \sum_{n \geq 0} e^{-an} \int_0^{n+1} f(t) \: \mathrm{d} t \\
& \leq \sum_{n \geq 0} e^{-an} e^{n+1} \\
& = e \sum_{n \geq 0}e^{(1-a)n}
\end{align*}
and this is finite since $a > 1$.

Comment: One quick question. How do we justify the split up of the integral? Integrals are countably additive only when the function is integrable. So it would seem you are assuming what you are trying to prove. Perhaps doing the steps in reverse adn applying the MCT would do the trick?

Comment: Correct, but it is allowed here because the integrand is positive, so the integral is either finite or infinite, but there are no cancellations or oscillations. It is the MCT behind this indeed, which works for finite or infinite quantities, unlike the DCT.

Answer (score 1):

For integration by parts to hold on a closed and bounded interval, it suffices that the functions in question are continuously differentiable (here, that is your $h(x)$ and the exponential). In general, however, one must be careful if the interval is unbounded. For instance, taking $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, one can erroneously use IBP on an interval $(1,n]$ to "reduce" the problem to the integrability of $\frac{\cos x}{x^2}$ and take limits. However, the former is not Lebesgue integrable over $(1, \infty)$ (split into intervals that are integer multiples of $\pi$) whereas the latter is. The lesson is that integration by parts cannot always be  used to infer the existence of one integral from another.

In this case, your integrand is non-negative, so you should be able to apply the monotone convergence theorem and get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate over a finite  interval $[0,x]$ using integration by parts. You get an upper bound 
$$\int^x_0f(t)e^{-at}\,dt=h(x)e^{-ax}+a\int^x _0 h(s)e^{-as}\,ds\leq e^{-x(a-1)}+a\int^x_0 e^{-s(a-1)}\,ds$$

where $h(x)=\int^x_0f$. Then let $x\rightarrow\infty$. You will require $f$ to be also locally integrable. Then your $h$ will satisfy the needed conditions for integration by parts (local finite variation)